# Can I configure Terraform to not use "env:" in the path for a workspace's state file path on S3?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using S3 for a remote state with Terraform.

When I use a Terraform workspace then the path for the state file for the environment ends up being `s3://<bucket>/env:/<workspace>/<key>` where `<bucket>` and `key` are specified in a `terraform` block. For example, with the below Terraform HCL:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "devops"
    key = "tf-state/abc/xyz.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

If we're using a Terraform workspace, like so:

```
$ terraform workspace new myapp-dev
$ terraform workspace select myapp-dev
$ terraform init
$ terraform apply
```

then we'll end up with the Terraform state file in the following path: `s3://devops/env:/myapp-dev/tf-state/abc/xyz.tfstate`

It seems that Terraform by default uses a subdirectory named `env:` under which it manages state files associated with workspaces. My question is can we add anything into the Terraform configuration that will allow us some control over the `env:` part of this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using a non-default workspace, the state path in the S3 bucket includes the
value of [`workspace_key_prefix`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html#workspace_key_prefix), like:

```
/<workspace_key_prefix>/<workspace_name>/<key>
```

The default value of `workspace_key_prefix` is `env:`. You could change your configuration to something like:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "devops"
    key = "terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
    workspace_key_prefix = "tf-state"
  }
}
```

Then, when using the `myapp-dev` workspace, the state file will be `s3://devops/tf-state/myapp-dev/terraform.tfstate`.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: Thank you. You saved my time. I noticed the default workspace state file will go to the root directory of the S3. How this state merge works. I need to run everything in other workspaces (env1, env2, etc) using the default workspace.